# NunoMaduro/Collision fatal error on php artisan:make migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I run the command `php artisan:make migration`, I have this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer::write(Whoops\Exception\Inspector $inspector): NunoMaduro\Collision\void must be compatible with NunoMaduro\Collision\Contracts\Writer::write(Whoops\Exception\Inspector $inspector): NunoMaduro\Collision\Contracts\void in /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Writer.php on line 27

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Declaration of NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer::write(Whoops\Exception\Inspector $inspector): NunoMaduro\Collision\void must be compatible with NunoMaduro\Collision\Contracts\Writer::write(Whoops\Exception\Inspector $inspector): NunoMaduro\Collision\Contracts\void

  at /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Writer.php:27    23|  * This is an Collision Writer implementation.
    24|  *    25|  * @author Nuno Maduro <enunomaduro@gmail.com>
    26|  */  > 27| class Writer implements WriterContract    28| {
    29|     /**    30|      * The number of frames if no verbosity is specified.    31|      */

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer::write() must be an instance of NunoMaduro\Collision\void, none returned in /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Writer.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Handler.php(48): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->write(Object(NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Inspector))
#1 /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Adapters/Laravel/ExceptionHandler.php(86): NunoMaduro\Collision\Handler->handle()
#2 /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(101): NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\ExceptionHandler->renderForConsole(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#3 /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(Symfony\Com in /home/gregory/folbet/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Writer.php on line 114
```

How can I fix it ?

My Laravel version is 5.6.* and my PHP version is ^7.1.3

Comment: are you using nunomaduro/collision v2.0.2?

Comment: This is what my composer.json says : "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0"

Comment: That's ok i guess. Packagist says is compatible. I would recommend opening an issue on github

Comment: That's what I just did, thanks.